# Select dentro de un Insert

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla que requiere de un dato de otra tabla, la estructura es la siguiente

```
INSERT INTO camaras (id_marca, modelo, flash, precio_renta)
VALUES ((SELECT id_marca FROM marcas WHERE marcas.nombre_marca = 'Leica'), 'M5', 1, 1300)
```

El valor de **id_camara** que insertare en la tabla **camaras** nesecito extraerlo de la tabla **marcas**, pero no consigo estructurarlo.

El error que me genera es **#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintaxis cerca ' VALUES)) ' en la línea 2**

Comment: Hola @Mike te genera algún error por favor de ponerlo. Gracias

Comment: Por pereza no lo había hecho, es complicado hacerlo desde el teléfono jeje, ya agregué las información, gracias :)

Comment: Concretamente nesecito que al registrar una cámara nueva el usuario pueda poner el nombre de la marca, pero a la hora de registrarse lo haga con el id de la marca, por ello tengo la tabla de marcas que contiene los nombres de las marcas y sus correspondientes ID

Comment: Sería mas sencillo si relacionaras la tabla `camaras` con `marca` así solo pasarías el `id_marca` como llave foránea de `camaras`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa la documentación de [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) con sql.

1. Estableces la tabla sobre la que se insertara
2. Cada campo seleccionado se proyectara sobre cada valor de columna a insertar

Agrego código adaptado a tu caso.

```
INSERT INTO camaras (id_marca, modelo, flash, precio_renta)
SELECT id_marca, 'elmodelo', 'elflash', 100 FROM marcas
WHERE marcas.nombre_marca = 'Leica';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!